# --test option is not available for /sbin/init

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, init

According to `man init(1)` it is a `--test` option should be available. In fact when I am trying to test it I got an error

```
root@mst-sls:~# /sbin/init --test
/sbin/init: unrecognized option '--test'
```

What is it not recognized?

Answer (score 3):

Also from [`man init`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/artful/en/man1/init.1.html):

```
For compatibility with SysV, if systemd is called as init and a PID
that is not 1, it will execute telinit and pass all command line
arguments unmodified. That means init and telinit are mostly equivalent
when invoked from normal login sessions. See telinit(8) for more
information.
```

So the way you're running `init`, all arguments are passed to `telinit`, and `telinit` does not have a `--test` option.

You can call `systemd` directly instead:

```
systemd --test
```

Comment: @l00p is that supposed to mean something?

Comment: yes, does the statement `systemd is called as init and a PID
that is not 1` is correct if output of `ps -P 1` is as follows `1 ?        00:00:01 systemd` ?

Comment: @l00p and did you pass the `--test` option to systemd run as PID 1?

Comment: I think that you mean that in my case `systemd` is not called as init. Does it mean that `telinit(8)` program is not passed anything?

Comment: @l00p no, what I meant is that, when you ran `init --test`, do you think that process's PID was 1?